# file_get_contents returns "Error in exception handler"?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Im having problems reading contents from a specific URL. This simple script

```
<?php
$str = @file_get_contents("http://neginmirsalehi.com");
echo $str;
?>
```

Only outputs: "Error in exception handler."

I tryed with curl also, but same problem!

Is it some kind of protection on that site? But strange error.

Comment: [`@`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) suppresses errors. You probably don't want to do that right while you're trying to fix your problem.

Comment: OK...seems to be a file_gets_contents problem. Site was running php version 5.2.17. Just tryed on a site running php version 5.6.6 and it works fine!

Comment: Thanks, Jon. My mistake :) But no further help. I just have to update php i guess.

Answer (score 1):

No, cURL does work, just setup the browser agent option:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://neginmirsalehi.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yevawU)

Also, `file_get_contents` with additional stream context with an agent also works as well:

```
$options  = array('http' => array('user_agent' => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)'));
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents('http://neginmirsalehi.com', false, $context);
echo $response;
```

Comment: Great. Thank you. The browser agent option works perfectly! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need indicate file name,not just url

```
<?php
$str = @file_get_contents("/dir/dir/file_name.extension");
echo $str;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$u = 'http://neginmirsalehi.com';
$c = curl_init($u);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'moz');
$r = curl_exec($c);

print_r($r);
```

works fine